# Convert return Promise into return Observable

Tags: promise, observable

I don't know how I can convert this expression

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  result.length === 0 ? resolve() : reject(result)
);
```

using Observable in the place of Promise. 'result' is the variable that I would return in case of error.

Answer (score 1):

More context would be helpful, as Observables and Promises work in slightly different ways. But to answer the question, `rxjs` provides a `from` method to generate an observable from an existing promise.

```js
import { from } from "rxjs";

// Define a function to return your promise
function getMyPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    result.length === 0 ? resolve() : reject(result)
  );
}

// Convert your promise to an observable
const wrappedPromise1$ = from(getMyPromise());
```

Again, you shouldn't expect to be able to just convert, plug, and play, as there are [some nuanced differences](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/javascript-theory-promise-vs-observable-d3087bc1239a) between the two.